# Assigning different BASE_URL for developer mode only

Tags: nginx, varnish, development, developer-mode, production-mode

I that possible?

I want to do this to set up a configuration like this:

`https://mystore.mydomain.com/` for production (with Varnish cache)

`https://mystore.mydomain.com:5001/` for development (bypassing Varnish cache)

How to do that? (note: I am using `Nginx`)

Answer (score 1):

your development must be separated from live. it is better for security and maintenance.

just copy your magento installation to another account / home folder.
copy nginx config, update root, domain and base url.

in varnish you need to add either one:
full domain bypass:

```
if (req.http.host ~ "^dev\.example\.com$") { return (pass); }
```

or parameter `?developer` bypass:

```
if (req.url ~ "[\?&]developer") { return (pass); }
```

to track all files and changes and easily sync files between - use **github** repository.